# isset(Input::old('abc') in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The code i used in the something.blade.php is

```
{{ Form::text('fullname', isset(Input::old('fullname'))?Input::old('fullname'):$hello[1] }}
```

but i not sure why it will return me the following error

> Can't use function return value in write context

Been trying with isset, trim, empty but nothing could work.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not closed your parenthesis:

```
{{ Form::text('fullname', Input::old('fullname') ? Input::old('fullname') : $hello[1]) }}
```

Also, the input will return a null (not undefined), and I've changed that as well.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use this

```
{{ Form::text('fullname', Input::old('fullname', $hello[1] ?: '' ) }}
```

`Input::old()` takes a default value, optionally. If the old value is available then old value will be used other the deafult value.

Answer (score 4):

`isset` is weird like that. You can't use a function in it, as its not for testing if a function returns a value but rather if a variable is actually set.

The simplest solution is:

```
if(Input::old('fullname'))
```

That will return `null` if fullname isn't set.

Alternatively :

```
$old = Input::old();
isset($old['fullname']) ...
```

(I suggest passing in variables into your view from your controller instead of using function calls in the view (with some exceptions of course)

Answer (score 2):

You can add second parameter to be the default value or you can place conditional on it.

example:

`old('field_name', 'default)` or `old('field_name', $user ? $user->field_name : '' )`

Comment: you forgot the string closing symbol in the first example ;) But nice answer